# Extracting indices from an R matrix to form a new matrix, using for-loops

Tags: r

I am learning R, and currently am learning about loops.
I have a task to create a function ans(A) which:

1) Takes as input a 10x10 matrix A, with values 1 and 0. (so like "true and false")

2) Takes the elements which are value 1, and saves them in a new 2-column matrix. The first column is the row index, and the second column is the column index. It then returns this new index matrix. The index matrix is formed with matrix().

**The task suggests the use of two nested for-loops**

I'm not really sure how to do this task, particularly with for-loops. The input matrix A can be created for example by a simple diag(10), before the function itself, and then used as the input for the function for testing purposes.

The function would using for-loops take the diagonal indices and insert them into a new matrix and then return it as the answer.

Comment: What have you tried up to this point?

Answer (score 0):

For the case you describe there is no need for any kind of loop:

```
set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace = T), ncol=10)
mat.ind <- which(mat==T, arr.ind=T)
> mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    1     1
 [2,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [4,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    1     1
 [5,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1     1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1     1
 [7,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0     1
 [9,]    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0     1
[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     1

> mat.ind
      row col
 [1,]   1   1
 [2,]   2   1
 [3,]   4   1
 [4,]   5   1
 [5,]   6   1
 [6,]   7   1
  ... ... ...
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into this method more. It seems to give the correct final result which im after, just gotta modify it to a function form. (So the function ans(A) would return that final index matrix, with A being the big matrix). I wonder why the task recommends a for loop system.